# Enabling Parallelism with Cython

Tags: multithreading, openmp, cython, cythonize

I am trying to get the `prange` function of Cython's `parallel` package to work and it seems like there is no parallelism in effect. To have a MWE, I have taken the example code from the book [Cython: A Guide for Python Programmers](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ERFkBgAAQBAJ&dq=environment%20variables%20for%20cython%20prange&source=gbs_navlinks_s) and modified it a little bit by adding a few print statements. The example code is freely available at [github](https://github.com/cythonbook/examples) and the code I'm referring to is at: examples/12-parallel-cython/02-prange-parallel-loops/.

The following is my modification of the julia.pyx file.

```
# distutils: extra_compile_args = -fopenmp
# distutils: extra_link_args = -fopenmp

from cython cimport boundscheck, wraparound
from cython cimport parallel

import numpy as np

cdef inline double norm2(double complex z) nogil:
    return z.real * z.real + z.imag * z.imag


cdef int escape(double complex z,
                double complex c,
                double z_max,
                int n_max) nogil:

    cdef:
        int i = 0
        double z_max2 = z_max * z_max

    while norm2(z) < z_max2 and i < n_max:
        z = z * z + c
        i += 1

    return i


@boundscheck(False)
@wraparound(False)
def calc_julia(int resolution, double complex c,
               double bound=1.5, double z_max=4.0, int n_max=1000):

    cdef:
        double step = 2.0 * bound / resolution
        int i, j
        double complex z
        double real, imag
        int[:, ::1] counts

    counts = np.zeros((resolution+1, resolution+1), dtype=np.int32)

    for i in parallel.prange(resolution + 1, nogil=True,
                    schedule='static', chunksize=1):
        real = -bound + i * step
        for j in range(resolution + 1):
            imag = -bound + j * step
            z = real + imag * 1j
            counts[i,j] = escape(z, c, z_max, n_max)

    return np.asarray(counts)

@boundscheck(False)
@wraparound(False)
def julia_fraction(int[:,::1] counts, int maxval=1000):
    cdef:
        unsigned int thread_id
        int total = 0
        int i, j, N, M
    N = counts.shape[0]; M = counts.shape[1]
    print("N = %d" % N)
    with nogil:
        for i in parallel.prange(N, schedule="static", chunksize=10):
            thread_id = parallel.threadid()
            with gil:
                print("Thread %d." % (thread_id))
            for j in range(M):
                if counts[i,j] == maxval:
                    total += 1
    return total / float(counts.size)
```

When I compile using the `setup_julia.py` given by

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.extension import Extension

setup(name="julia",
      ext_modules=cythonize(Extension('julia', ['julia.pyx'], extra_compile_args=['-fopenmp'], extra_link_args=['-fopenmp'])))
```

with the command

`python setup_julia.py build_ext --inplace`

and run the run_julia.py file, I see that all instances of the for loop only use one thread -- `Thread 0`. The terminal output looks like below.

```
poulin8:02-prange-parallel-loops poulingroup$ python run_julia.py 
time: 0.892143
julia fraction: N = 1001
Thread 0.
Thread 0.
Thread 0.
Thread 0.
.
.
.
.
Thread 0.
0.236994773458
```

As I understand, the for loop is simply running in parallel. Could someone guide me on what I must do for initiating the for loop to distribute load amongst many threads?
I have also tried to set the system variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to some number greater than 1 and there is no effect of this.

I am running the tests on a OSX 10.11.6, with Python 2.7.10 and gcc 5.2.0.

Comment: You're reacquiring the GIL every iteration of the parallel loop. I think this is killing the loop's parallelism. Try to only reacquire the GIL every N iteration sof the parallel loop, where N is such that the loop is able to do a large amount of work between each instance of reacquiring the GIL.

Comment: @ngoldbaum It should still work (i.e. run on multiple threads) though, although less efficiently that without the `with gil: print...`

Comment: Try `fprintf("Thread %d\n", thread_id)` instead of python print. `fprintf` can be found in `stdio.h`.

Comment: @danny
That would be
```%%cython
from libc.stdio cimport FILE, stdout, fprintf
fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", <int>thread_id)```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem on Windows 7.
It was running serial.
Noticed compilation message:

`python setup_julia.py build_ext --inplace`

> cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp'

Apparently in Visual Studio it has to be `-openmp`

```
# distutils: extra_compile_args = -openmp
# distutils: extra_link_args = -openmp
```

Now runs in parallel.

As @danny noted you can use fprintf:

```
from cython.parallel cimport prange, threadid
from libc.stdio cimport stdout, fprintf

def julia_fraction(int[:,::1] counts, int maxval=1000):
   ...
   thread_id = threadid()
   fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", <int>thread_id)
   ...
```