# Benchmarking with Pytest Parallelized Cython Code results in Fatal Python Error

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pytest, cython, benchmarking

I have the following test:

```py
import array
def test_parallel_cython_clip(benchmark: Any) -> None:
    benchmark.pedantic(
        math_cython.parallel_cython_clip_vector,
        args=(array.array("f", [0.0]),-1.0,1.0,array.array("f", [0.0])),
        rounds=1,
        iterations=1
    )
```

that I execute via:

```
pytest --benchmark-columns=min,max,mean,stddev --benchmark-sort=mean benchmark.py -vv -k test_parallel_cython_clip
```

which results in the error:
`benchmark.py::test_parallel_cython_clip Fatal Python error: Aborted`

Furthermore the following information is provided:

```bash
Extension modules: mkl._mklinit, mkl._py_mkl_service, numpy.core._multiarray_umath, numpy.core._multiarray_tests, numpy.linalg._umath_linalg, numpy.fft._pocketfft_internal, numpy.random._common, numpy.random.bit_generator, numpy.random._bounded_integers, numpy.random._mt19937, numpy.random.mtrand, numpy.random._philox, numpy.random._pcg64, numpy.random._sfc64, numpy.random._generator, math_cython.cython_computations (total: 16)
```

The package folder `math_cython`, which is editable-installed into the conda environment, contains a `.py` module with the following entry:

```py
def parallel_cython_clip_vector(
    vector_in: array.array,
    min_value: float,
    max_value: float,
    vector_out: array.array,
) -> None:
    _parallel_cython_clip_vector(vector_in, min_value, max_value, vector_out)
```

and a `.pyx` file with the `_parallel_cython_clip_vector` function defined as follows:

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)  # Deactivate bounds checking (which is possible in Python, but not in C)
@cython.wraparound(False)  # Deactivate negative indexing (which is possible in Python, but not in C)
def _parallel_cython_clip_vector(
    float[:] vector_in,
    float min_value,
    float max_value,
    float[:] vector_out,
):
    cdef signed int idx = 0
    <this part I commented for the moment>
```

Operating System Info:

```bash
macOS 14.3.1 
Darwin 23.3.0
```

Installed Python libraries:

```
cython 3.0.6
pytest 8.0.0
pytest-benchmark 4.0.0
python 3.11.7
numpy 1.26.3
```

I saw similar questions here, but I do not think they address my issue:

- [Enabling Parallelism with Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46977293/enabling-parallelism-with-cython)
- [Cython prange fails with Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42131988/cython-prange-fails-with-fatal-python-error-pythreadstate-get-no-current-threa)
- [Cython crashed using memoryviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48780826/cython-crashed-using-memoryviews)

Any help to resolve the Fatal Python error would be very much appreciated.

EDIT: Running debugger in VSCode I got more information on the error:

```bash
OMP: Error #15: Initializing libomp.dylib, but found libiomp5.dylib already initialized.
OMP: Hint This means that multiple copies of the OpenMP runtime have been linked into the program. That is dangerous, since it can degrade performance or cause incorrect results. The best thing to do is to ensure that only a single OpenMP runtime is linked into the process, e.g. by avoiding static linking of the OpenMP runtime in any library. As an unsafe, unsupported, undocumented workaround you can set the environment variable KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=TRUE to allow the program to continue to execute, but that may cause crashes or silently produce incorrect results. For more information, please see http://openmp.llvm.org/
Fatal Python error: Aborted
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it (on Linux rather than OS X). If I were you I'd probably try to run it in a C debugger and see if you can work out where it's failing (but I couldn't advise on exactly how to do that on OS-X)

Comment: @DavidW Updated with debugger information.

Comment: Will try out variants proposed here, unfortunately there is no unified solution to the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53014306/error-15-initializing-libiomp5-dylib-but-found-libiomp5-dylib-already-initial

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem is:

`conda install nomkl`

The reasons why this is needed on MacOS is nicely explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58869103/9698518

I short there is a clash between Conda's Intel MKL Optimizations and macOS's own Accelerate Framework that also comes with OpenMP.